# How can I normalize text data containing LTR/RTL marks ('\u200e' etc.)?

Tags: python, unicode

Suppose I try to display a string like:

```
print("\u202eB\u2060A\u202c\u200e\u202eC")
```

The output appears like `ABC`. The `'\u200e'`, `'\u202c'`, `'\u202e'` and `'\u2060'` characters control the direction of text output.

How can I get a normalized version of the string, in this case `'ABC'`? I want to use the normalized string as a file name.

Simply removing the control codes from the string does not work, since the actual text is not in the final order. For example:

```
>>> text = "\u202eB\u2060A\u202c\u200e\u202eC"
>>> text.replace('\u202e', '').replace('\u202c', '').replace('\u2060', '').replace('\u200e', '')
'BAC'
```

I tried writing to a `StringIO` instance, but it doesn't solve anything. The output still appears correct, but the underlying string is not changed.

Comment: *If* you print the string somewhere that follows the Unicode bidi rules, the string prints “correct”. There isn’t any more “correct” string. Removing the control characters and reshuffling the string to just `'ABC'` is a completely different string…

Comment: This probably isn't the best solution, but one workaround is to create your own virtual file with `StringIO` (not an actual file on the hard disk), print to it, and then read the result from this. The code would be: `from io import StringIO`
``
`string = "\u202eB\u2060A\u202c\u200e\u202eC"`
`output = StringIO()`
`print(string, file=output)`
``
`value = output.getvalue()`
`print(value)` This produces the correct result of `'ABC'`

Comment: thank you all and esp to Lecdi. I tried this way and you may read my updates in the post.

Comment: OP wants to **normalize** the string such that it has only the non-BIDI-controlling characters, in the order that they would render after the [BIDI algorithm](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr9/) is applied.

Comment: I tried to [edit] the question to be clearer, using the appropriate terminology for the problem. I hope I have accurately explained it - please respond if it seems wrong now.

Comment: @Karl How would the result look for *actual* RTL text? In this case it’s theoretically possible to normalise to an equivalent looking string. But if it contained Arabic text, then what?

Comment: @Lecdi That’s all just passing the bytes through; it’s the visual text rendering system that’s doing the directionality, but you’re not getting the result of the visual rendering system this way, you’re just getting the original bytes back. You’d need to OCR the rendered text or something for the approach you’re thinking, but that’d be going a bit far for this task.

Comment: @Karl File names can be Arabic or virtually any other character you want on modern systems; and by that I mean most systems produced in the last two decades or so. If this is a solvable task at all, then only with certain caveats and within limits.

Comment: @Karl Thanks. Your edit is perfect!  The question is now much more clear.